# Подскажите, как реализовать древовидный вывод папок и подпапок?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace list_of_files
{
    class Program
    {

        private static void FilesandFolders(string Path1, int Level = 0)
        {
            string[] directory = Directory.GetDirectories(Path1);
            string[] set = Directory.GetFiles(Path1);

            try
            {
                foreach (string file in set)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("└" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                }

                foreach (string file in directory)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("+" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                    FilesandFolders(file, Level++);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Программа выводит каталог папок и файлов в заданной папке.");
            Console.Write("Введите имя папки: ");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ну вот где то так, просто вложил цикл в другой и все:

```
    private static void SearchFoldersAndFiles(String path, DirectoryInfo parent = null, String space = null)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        foreach (var item in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{space}+{item.Name}");
            SearchFoldersAndFiles(path + @"\" + item.Name, item.Parent, "\t");
            foreach (var file in item.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t\t└{file.Name}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Программа выводит каталог папок и файлов в заданной папке.");
        Console.Write("Введите имя папки: ");
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("   " + path);
        SearchFoldersAndFiles($@"{path}", null);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

P.S. можно еще поиграться с выводом)

Comment: Мне кажется будет лучше сделать два отдельных цикла. Посмотрите код выше, мб замечания появятся, да и буду благодарен, если предложите иной способ решения проблемы.

Comment: может и есть в этом логик но мне не нравится она)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{

    private static void FilesandFolders(string Path1, int down = 0)
    {
        string[] directory = Directory.GetDirectories(Path1);
        string[] set = Directory.GetFiles(Path1);
        try
        {
            foreach (string file in set)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', down) + "   └ " +  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
            }
            foreach (string file in directory)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', down) + "   + " +  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                FilesandFolders(file, down++);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Программа выводит каталог папок и файлов в заданной папке.");
        Console.Write("Введите имя папки: ");
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("   " + path);
        FilesandFolders(path, 0);
        Console.Read();
    }
```